# Protocols and exchange formats for financial data

Tags: software, historical-data, online-data-source, market-data

Wikipedia says:

> Many banks in the US let customers use personal financial management
>   software to automatically download their bank statements in OFX
>   format.

Also, from http://fixprotocol.org/adopters/ it seems that FIX protocol is widely adopted too.

Are there any other widely used formats or protocols?

Comment: Nope FIX isn't used for this specific area. It is for financial instrument transactions and related more on the commercial side between banks, traders etc.

Comment: I only wanted to ask about "the commercial side between banks, traders etc". Then it is OFX which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have so far seen, besides OFX

Quicken to also be an exported format although importing that takes more work than importing OFX which is basically XML

Answer (score 1):

FIX is industry standard for orders
FAST is FIX adopted for streaming quotes:
 http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/structure/tech-specs/fast-protocol

SWIFT is industry standard interbank (especially international):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIFT_message_types

Many exchanges have their own Native protocols, for example ISE's protocol:
http://www.ise.com/technology/connectivity/

Financial institutions and brokers may also provide their own proprietary APIs.
(you need to contact them directly)